# Support Fragment pop animation is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I am using v4 support fragments in my app. I have an activity where the user could see more info by clicking a button. The information screen should slide up from bottom, covering the activity and when the back is pressed, slides down. This is the code I am using at the moment

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.setCustomAnimations(
                             R.anim.fragment_bottom_enter, 
                             R.anim.fragment_bottom_exit,                                  
                             R.anim.fragment_bottom_exit, 
                             R.anim.fragment_bottom_exit
                    );                 
                    ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, TAG);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
```

**fragment_bottom_enter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p" />
</set>
```

**fragment_bottom_exit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toYDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

The above is working for the enter animation (the fragment slides from bottom as expected). But the pop animation is never played. I even tried with android's built in fade in and fade out animations to no avail. Any help on resolving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: put more details for pop.how ur calling pop?

Comment: I am not calling pop from code. I add the fragment to backstack and when the back button is pressed it gets popped

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but if anyone is still running into this issue like I was you need to use `fragmentTransaction.add()` instead of `fragmentTransaction.replace()` when adding the animated fragment.

Answer (score 1):

fragment set custom animation method is `setCustomAnimations(int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit)`.

- `enter`:fragment enter animation.
- `exit`:fragment exit animation, **!note if you call replace and you have a pre fragment, the pre fragment will run this animation**.
- `popEnter`: when fragment stack back to the fragment, it run this animation.
- `popExit`: when fragment out of fragment stack, it run this.

so you should call it like this:

```java
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom, 0, 0, R.anim.slide_out_to_bottom)
    .replace(getFragmentId(), fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
    .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
    .commit();
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I noticed that this happens only when the fragment container view (`R.id.fragmentContainer` in your case) has not a fixed dimension, in my case its height was `wrap_content`. After setting the height to a **fixed value** the pop animation worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

in your fragment activity you need to override the onBackpress method and call like below

```
 @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

then your fragment can pop from back stack.